# Send Photos via Email when accessing Camera from Lock Screen

Tags: iphone, photos

I access the camera from the lock screen all the time.  Often times I want to send those photos.  In order to send them I have to... close the camera app, reopen it, find the picture and then send it.  What a pain!

I know that Apple changed this because of some security problem, but is there anyway that it can be enabled to be able to mail photos when I access the camera app from the lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

Your out of luck for now as there is currently no way to enable this functionality with the stock iOS.  That being said if you are a jail breaker there IS a jailbreak app that enables this.  That jailbreak app is called 'LockShare'